# Отскакивает объект на платформе

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, методы, if

Я хочу сделать так чтоб объект (куб) не отскакивал на платформе. С помощью rigidbody и collider я написал код. Создал пустышку и задал траекторий объекта(куб), суть кода заключается в том что куб двигается по заданный траекторий и при нажатий мышки гравитация отключается. И куб падает на платформу, но когда куб падает на платформу куб отскакивает от платформы ну просто прыгает на платформе. А мне так не нужно мне нужно чтоб куб просто стоял на платформе. Надеюсь всё хорошо объяснил. Вот мой скрипт:

```
public Transform pos1, pos2;
public float speed;
public Transform startPos;
private Rigidbody rg;

Vector3 nextPos;

  void Start()
{
    nextPos = startPos.position;
    rg = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

 void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed);

    if(transform.position == pos1.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos2.position;
         
    }

    if (transform.position == pos2.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos1.position;
        
    }
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rg.useGravity = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Создай физик материал, навесь на куб, и играйся с настройками.

Answer (score 0):

> при нажатий мышки гравитация отключается

Если вы хотите, чтобы объект просто упал мертвым грузом, то в rigidbody нужно увеличить gravity scale

> мне нужно чтоб куб просто стоял на платформе

На сам объект надо повесить physics material, у которого bounciness будет равна 0.

Comment: у меня 3d объект, а в 3d объекте gravity scale нету же